# React js. Cant' get value of undefined, displayName of user. I have used props to use the user state in this file but it can't access any of user data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't display users data such as `name` when he is logged in. I have used `props` and `state` user as `currentUser` but i am unable to access these fields since the error says that it can't read property of undefined.

[image]

```
class UserPanel extends React.Component {

    state = { user: this.props.currentUser }

    dropdownOptions = () => [
        {
            key: "user",
            text: (
                <span>
                    Sign in as <strong>{this.state.user.displayName}</strong>
                </span>
            ),
            disabled: true
        },
        {
            key: "avatar",
            text: <span>Change Avatar</span>
        },
        {
            key: "signout",
            // Set a signout Function to enable user to sign out of the chat
            text: <span onClick={event => this.handleSignOut(event)}>SignOut</span>
        }
    ];

    handleSignOut = (event) => {
        // You need to prevent form submission. Use event.preventDefault() in your handle submit function.
        event.preventDefault();
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => console.log("See you"));
    } 

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.currentUser);
        return (
            <Grid style={{ background: '#4c3c4c' }}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Row style={{ padding: '1.2rem', margin: 0 }}>
                        <Header inverted floated='left' as='h2'>
                            <Icon name='code' />
                            <Header.Content>VirtualChat</Header.Content>
                        </Header>
                    </Grid.Row>


                    {/* User Dropdown Choices */}
                    <Header style={{ padding: "0.25em" }} as="h4" inverted>
                        <Dropdown 
                        trigger={<span>{this.state.user.displayName}</span>}
                        options={this.dropdownOptions()}
                        />
                    </Header>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
// index.js
const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools());



// change root component to a statefull component 
class Root extends React.Component { 

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            // If firebase has detect a user
            if (user) {
                // console.log(user);
                this.props.setUser(user);
                // We will redirect them to the home Route
                this.props.history.push("/");
            } else {
                // In case user signout 
                this.props.history.push('/login');
                this.props.clearUser();
            }

        });
    }

    render(){
        return this.props.isLoading ? <Spinner /> : (
        //  All of our indivicuals routes will be nested in switch component which is nested to router component
            <Switch>
                {/* Root route of the app, we first set the path and then which component we watn  */}
                {/* We added exact keyword in order to secure that the main route will not match multiple components */}
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} /> 
                {/* Create routes for Login and Register */}
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
            </Switch>
         ); 


    }
} 

// To get loading data from our state object to see when user actions is loaded
const mapStateFromProps = state => ({
    isLoading: state.user.isLoading
});

const RootWithAuth = withRouter(
    connect(
        // Using mapStateFromProps because, since state update are asynchronous and take some amount of time
        mapStateFromProps, 
        { setUser, clearUser }
        )(Root)
);


// We render root because app is now our route
// In order to provide this global state/store to the other components we wrap the router in to a provider
// Provider will provide this global state to any component who want to make use of it
ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
        <RootWithAuth />
        </Router>
        </Provider>, 
        document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the value is **undefined** because you are not checking if the `props` has a value maybe the data that your are trying to render is not ready or is **async**. To handle this you can set your `state` in a `componentDidMount` so if the `state.currentUser` is `null`  it means that the data isn't ready and you can render a loader or something similar.

```
class UserPanel extends React.Component {

    state = { user: null }

    dropdownOptions = () => [
        {
            key: "user",
            text: (
                <span>
                    Sign in as <strong>{this.state.user.displayName}</strong>
                </span>
            ),
            disabled: true
        },
        {
            key: "avatar",
            text: <span>Change Avatar</span>
        },
        {
            key: "signout",
            // Set a signout Function to enable user to sign out of the chat
            text: <span onClick={event => this.handleSignOut(event)}>SignOut</span>
        }
    ];

    handleSignOut = (event) => {
        // You need to prevent form submission. Use event.preventDefault() in your handle submit function.
        event.preventDefault();
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => console.log("See you"));
    } 
    componentDidMount(){
     this.setState({ user: this.props.currentUser })
    }
    render(){
        if( !this.state.user){
          return <div>Curernt User doesnt exist!</div>
        }
        return (
            <Grid style={{ background: '#4c3c4c' }}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Row style={{ padding: '1.2rem', margin: 0 }}>
                        <Header inverted floated='left' as='h2'>
                            <Icon name='code' />
                            <Header.Content>VirtualChat</Header.Content>
                        </Header>
                    </Grid.Row>


                    {/* User Dropdown Choices */}
                    <Header style={{ padding: "0.25em" }} as="h4" inverted>
                        <Dropdown 
                        trigger={<span>{this.state.user.displayName}</span>}
                        options={this.dropdownOptions()}
                        />
                    </Header>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the user data wasn't ready. But i still get an error about (UserPanel(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.).

Comment: if (user) {

  this.props.setUser(user);
  this.props.history.push("/");

Comment: Could you update your code ?, maybe you are missing something

Comment: I added the main part as a snippet, error says nothing returned from the render

Comment: I added a spinner until the data are ready but it never stops, which means it can't access the data.

Comment: Yep. you need to update the **isLoading** prop, when the data is ready. so the ````Spinner```` condition is missed and render the ````Switch````, but i cant see where are you handling the **isLoading**

Comment: If i remove the spinner it displays the prop error from index.js. The spinner was just to check how long it takes to get the data, but it can't access them.

Answer (score -1):

You call `this.props.state.user` instead of `this.state.user`

Comment: i have updated the image with errors, i still get the same.

Comment: Does console print any data when you log `this.props.currentUser`?

Comment: It seems like it can't access the data